# Paint over the top of a swing Icon?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I am rendering a bunch of JLabels that contain icons. I would like to conditionally annotate these icons by drawing some sort of line or symbol over the top of them. Is it possible to draw on top of an icon in swing? Example of what my JLabel looks like bellow:

[image]

The class I use to encapsulate my *waypoint* component that contains my JLabels:

```java
/**
 * Waypoint to be drawn on the map
 */
public class Waypoint extends DefaultWaypoint {
    protected JLabel label;
    private final long id;
    private final EntityType type;

    public Waypoint( long id ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = null;
        this.label = null;
    }

    public Waypoint( long id, EntityType type, Location coord ) {
        super( locToGeoPos(coord) );
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.label = new JLabel();
    }

    public void setIcon( ImageIcon icon ) {
        label = new JLabel( icon, JLabel.CENTER );
        label.setBorder( new LineBorder(Color.BLACK) );

      }

    public void setBackgroundColor( Color bgrColor ) {
        label.setOpaque( true );
        label.setBackground( bgrColor );
    }

    public void setToolTipText( String tooltipText ) {
        label.setToolTipText( "<html>" + tooltipText + "</html>" );
    }

    public JLabel getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void annotateIcon() {
        // TODO
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible, make a class that extends JLabel and then override the paintComponent method. Here is the "official" tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Comment: `JLabel` is a complex component, that deals with text, image and various alignment options, trying to extend it to provide a custom "overlay" might not be the best solution available to you.  Personally, I'd consider creating a new image, using the base image and what ever else you want overlay on it, and the assign that to the label, it would provide you with a much high level of customisation and would generally be easier

Comment: *Is it possible to draw on top of an icon in swing?* - You could use the [Compound Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/). It will allow you to paint a second Icon on top of the original icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

```java
        Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMAGE PATH HERE"));
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon, JLabel.CENTER) {

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.drawOval(0, 0, 10, 10);
            }
        };
```

Here, I have overritten the `paintComponent` method of the `JLabel` class. The `super.paintComponent();` line will perform the default painting of the component. We simply paint of top of it after.

Comment: Note that you can/should call `super.paintComponent(g);` to perform normal painting before we do our custom painting, this would also allow the border to be drawn correctly and would daw any images set previously using normal means.

Comment: Note that your code will still draw over top of any previously set JLabel border. OP does set a border in his code which won't work, instead, a border will need to be drawn manually using `g.drawRect(...)` after drawing the image.

Comment: Just beware, that `JLabel` is a complex component, that deals with text, images and various alignment attributes - starting with `JLabel` may not be the "best" long term solution

Comment: `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);`

Comment: @AndrewThompson Not according to the Java Tutorials. They always specify the observer as null.

Comment: (1-) *because we now need to use the Image only* - no you don't. The super.paintComponent() will paint the icon of the label.  If you are going to draw both the image and oval then you should extend JComponent or JPanel so you don't inherit the JLabel custom painting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it like this.  This is a complete working example.  You can scale the icon as appropriate.  This draws the image.  Waits 2 seconds and then draws a diagonal red line over the image.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawingOverIcon extends JPanel {
    
    
    static JFrame f = new JFrame();
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DrawingOverIcon doi = new DrawingOverIcon();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("f:/download.png");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        doi.setBackground(Color.white);
        f.add(doi);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        
        doi.add(label);
        doi.repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }

        // From here down is what you would do to modify the
        // icon.
        Image image = icon.getImage();
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null),
                image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        
        Graphics2D g2d =
                (Graphics2D) bi.getGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 500, 500);
        icon.setImage(bi);
        doi.repaint();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: A very efficient solution if you only need to draw on the image once for the duration of the application. To restore/change the image later simply load it from file again and change as needed.